# Max Heap that allows for change key

Tags: java, key, max, heap

Does anyone know of a max heap implementation in Java that allows you to add elements with certain keys and then it would keep them inside the heap in some way so that it could get the max-key element in constant time. And also it would allow you to change the key of certain elements in O(log n) time. I think this would imply that the heap keeps track of where each element in the heap is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple implementation of all the operations on heap with time complexity indicated in comments as well as some explanation.You can remove the comments character in main method to
see the working of other operations. Feel free for any queries any time.

```
/*ALL DISCUSSION IS IN CONTEXT OF MAX HEAP.EXTRACTING THE MAX OR MIN TAKES O(LOG N) TIME. FIRST WE REMOVE THE VERY FIRST ELEMENT WHICH IS THE MAXIMUM (OR THE MINIMUM.
     * (IN CASE OF MIN HEAP)THEN WE PUT THE LAST ELEMENT IN FRONT POSITION. THIS TAKES CONSTANT TIME.THEN WE INITIATE HEAPIFY AT POSITION 1, WHICH WILL
     * TAKE TIME O(LOGN) BECAUSE HEIGHT AT POSITION 1 IS H AND HEAPIFY INITIATED AT HEIGHT H TAKES O(H) TIME.SO THE TIME COMPLEXITY 
     * OF THIS ALGO IS O(LOG N) WHERE HEIGHT OF HEAP=H=LOG N. 
     */


import java.util.*;
class HEAP
{
 private LinkedList<Integer> heap;

 public static void main(String []args)
 {
     Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("enter the number elements in the heap");
     int n=s.nextInt();
     HEAP o = new HEAP();
     o.heap=new LinkedList<Integer>();
     for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
      o.heap.add(s.nextInt());


     o.build_heap();
     o.heapsort();
     System.out.println("the sorted elements are");
     for(int e:o.heap)
      System.out.println(e);
     /*   
     //int max=o.extract_max();
     System.out.println();
     o.insert(300);
     System.out.println("Max Heap is");
     for(int e:o.heap)
      System.out.print(e+" ");
     o.increase_key(3,900);
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("Max Heap is");
     for(int e:o.heap)
      System.out.print(e+" ");*/
 }
 public void build_heap()
 {
     for(int i=heap.size()/2;i>=1;--i)
      heapify(i,heap.size());
 }
 public int extract_max()
 {
     int max=heap.remove(0);
     int last=heap.remove(heap.size()-1);
     heap.add(0,last);
     heapify(1,heap.size());
     return max;
 }
 public void heapify(int i,int size)
 {
     int l=2*i,r=l+1;
     int largest;
     if(l<=size&&heap.get(l-1)>heap.get(i-1))
      largest=l;
     else largest=i;

     if(r<=size&&heap.get(r-1)>heap.get(largest-1))
      largest=r;
     if(largest!=i)
     {
         int temp=heap.get(i-1);
         heap.set(i-1,heap.get(largest-1));
         heap.set(largest-1,temp);
         heapify(largest,size);
     }    
 }   


 /*ITS PRETTY STRAIGHT FORWARD ALGORITHM FIRST U INCREASE THE KEY AND THEN YOU BEGIN THE COMPARISON WITH THE PARENT BECAUSE U HAVE
  * INCREASED SO THE CHILD SUBTREES WOULD BE ALRIGHT ALL U HAVE TO DO IS BEGIN COMPARISON WITH THE PARENT AND GO ON TILL ROOT IF
  * U HAVE TO. TIME TAKEN IS O(LOG N). WORST CASE OCCURS WHEN FROM LEAF YOU TRAVEL ALL THE WAY UP TO ROOT.
  */
 public void increase_key(int i,int k)
 {
     if(k<= heap.get(i-1))
      System.out.println("The increase_key did not go all the way through");
     int temp;
     heap.set(i-1,k);
     /*Now the left and right subtrees are fine but its parent may be upset so get to it and do this till root if you have to*/
     while(i>1&&heap.get(i-1)> heap.get(i/2-1))
     {
        temp=heap.get(i-1);
        heap.set(i-1,heap.get(i/2-1));
        heap.set(i/2-1,temp);
        i=i/2;
     }
 }
 /*IT IS ALSO A PRETTY STRAIGHT FORWARD ALGORITHM. YOU DECREASE THE KEY NOW CAUSE ITS MAX HEAP THE PARENT IS ALL FINE BUT THE 
  * CHILD MAY BE UPSET SO BEST THING TO DO IS TO CALL THE HEAPIFY ALGORITHM FROM THE INDICATED POSITION.WORST CASE TIME TAKEN IS
  * OR SIMPLY THE TIME TAKEN IS O(LOG N). WORST CASE OCCURS WHEN FROM ROOT YOU GO ALL THE WAY TO LEAF.
  */
 public void decrease_key(int i,int k)
 {
     if(k>=heap.get(i-1))
      System.out.println("The increase_key did not go all the way through");
     heap.set(i-1,k);
     /*Now after decreasing the key the parent is fine but the child may be upset so why not call heapify*/
     heapify(i,heap.size());
 }
 /*INSERT IS ALSO PRETTY MUCH STRAIGHT FORWORD BECAUSE . SIMPLY INSERT AT LAST POSITION. THEN START THE COMPARISON FROM ITS PARENT
  * AND THIS BUSINESS MAY CONTINUE ALL THE WAY UP TO THE ROOT. HENCE THE TIME TAKEN IS O(LOG N) AND THE WORST CASE OCCURS WHEN
  * THE BUSINESS DOES REALLY GO UP TO THE ROOT. REMEMBER WHEN WE MENTION THAT TIME TAKEN IS O(LOG N), IT ALSO MEANS THAT THIS IS
  * THE WORST TIME BECAUSE IT MEANS THAT IN NO CASE THE TIME TAKEN CAN BE GREATER THAN CLOG N , C>0. BUT THIS DOES NOT NECESSARILY
  * MEAN IT IS ALWAYS THE TIME.
  */
 public void insert(int k)
 {
     /*element inserted at last position and from its parent work begins of comparing and will go on till root if it has to*/     
     heap.add(k);     
     int temp;
     int i=heap.size();
     while(i>1&&heap.get(i/2-1)<heap.get(i-1))
     {
        temp=heap.get(i-1);
        heap.set(i-1,heap.get(i/2-1));
        heap.set(i/2-1,temp);
        i=i/2;
     }
 }
 /*HEAPSORT IS VERY CLEVER ALGORITHM THAT TAKES NLOG(N) TIME IN ALL CASES AND IS IN PLACE. MERGESORT IS AN ALGORITHM HAS TIME
  * PERFORMANCE EQUIVALENT TO HEAPSORT BUT ITS SPACE COMPLEXITY IS ALWAYS LINEAR. QUICKSORT IS INPLACE BUT IN WORST CASE IT TAKES
  * TIME QUADRATIC. HEAPSORT IS A WIN WIN SITUATION, IT SEEMS TO BE BECAUSE IT WINS OVER BOTH QUICKSORT AND MERGESORT.HEAPSORT
  * DOES NOT MAKE USE OF CACHE MEMORY BECAUSE THERE IS NO LOCALITY OF REFERENCE AND THE REFERECES ARE SPREAD OUT IN MEMORY. 
  * TECHNIQUE IS VERY SIMPLE. THE LARGEST ELEMENT IS FIRST ONE SO WE SWAP IT WITH THE LAST ELEMENT AND DECREASE THE HEAP SIZE BY
  * ONE AND THEN CALL HEAPIFY(1) SO THAT IT DOES NOT EFFECT THE LAST ELEMENT AS WE HAVE DECREMENTED THE SIZE BY ONE.ALSO THE LAST
  * ELEMENT IS AT ITS CORRECT POSITION, THAT IS WHY WE DO NOT WANT TO DISTURB IT AND THEREFORE WE DECREASE THE SIZE BY ONE. WE WILL
  * REPEAT THIS STEP N-1 TIMES BECAUSE THE SMALLEST ELEMENT WILL AUTOMATICALLY BE IN ITS APPROPRIATE PLACE.
  * 
  * HEAPSORT HOWEVER IS NOT PREFERRED.THE REASON IS:
  * 
  * HEAPSORT IS NOT A STABLE SORTING ALGORITHM. THE REASON IS BECAUSE IT DOES NOT PRESERVE THE RELATIVE ORDER OF THE ELEMENTS WITH
  * SAME KEY. SAY THE HEAP IN STARTING OF THE ALGO IS A C ..... D D ......S. SO WHEN THE SORTING WILL BE DONE, THE D ON THE LEFT 
  * WILL BE REMOVED FIRST AND THEN THE D ON RIGHT WILL BE REMOVED, THIS IS KIND OF SWAPPING OF THE POSITIONS AND THIS IS THE REASON
  * WHY HEAPSORT IS NOT STABLE.
  * SECONDLY HEAPSORT IS NOT CACHE FRIENDLY DUE TO LACK OF LOCALITY OF REFERENCE. THE REFERENCES IN THE ARRAY ARE MADE IN SUCH WAY
  * THAT THE CACHE MISS ARE MORE THAN IN THE CASE OF QUICKSORT.
  */
 public void heapsort()
 {
     LinkedList<Integer> sorted=new LinkedList<Integer>();
     int k=heap.size();
     for(int i=1;i<heap.size();++i)
     {
      int temp=heap.get(0);
      heap.set(0,heap.get(k-1));
      heap.set(k-1,temp);
      heapify(1,--k);
      System.out.println();
      for(int e:heap)
       System.out.print(e+" ");
     }      
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on doing lots of increase key operations, then you may want to look at Fibonacci heaps or Brodal queues because they provide better asymptotic complexity for the increase key operation. A Google search for those specific names with the Java keyword will probably find what you need.

Here's one that I found:

http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=fibonacci-heap

Comment: That really doesn't work for me because I need a Max Heap so I could use the min heap and just make all my values negative but then I would need an increase key and this only has a decrease key.

Comment: For min heaps you can typically only decrease-key and for max-heaps you can typically only increase-key. The heapify operation on the subtree is equivalent to increase-key and will have O(log n) time.